# How to replace json node in jsonNode or ObjectNode

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml, jsonnode

I have a `JSON` node-like below. The structure of `JsonNode` will change *dynamically*.

Now I want to `replace/update` the value of a particular key.

**Sample JSON One**

```
{
  "company": "xyz",
  "employee": {
    "name": "abc",
    "address": {
      "zipcode": "021566"
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample JSON Two**

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "address": {
    "zipcode": "021566"
  }
}
```

I want to replace the zip code value `021566` to `566258`. I know key `name (zipcode)`, old and new zip code value but I don't know the path of zip code. I tried multiple ways using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode - put, replace`

Is there any way to update in java?

Comment: You need to write a (recursive) code that iterates through your JsonNode and finds the relevant key for you and replaces it's value, if found.

Answer (score 1):

JsonNodes are immutable, but you can find the value you want from a JsonNode, cast the original to an ObjectNode, replace the value, then cast that back to a JsonNode. It's a little odd, I know, but it worked for me.

```java
  public static void findAndReplaceJsonNode throws JsonProcessingException {
    String jsonOne = "{ \"company\" : \"xyz\", \"address\" : { \"zipcode\" : \"021566\", \"state\" : \"FL\" } }";
    String jsonTwo = "{ \"company\" : \"abc\", \"address\" : { \"zipcode\" : \"566258\", \"state\" : \"FL\" } }";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode nodeOne = mapper.readTree(jsonOne);
    JsonNode nodeTwo = mapper.readTree(jsonTwo);

    JsonNode findNode = nodeTwo.get("address");

    ObjectNode objNode = (ObjectNode) nodeOne;
    objNode.replace("address", findNode);
    nodeOne = (JsonNode) objNode;

    System.out.println(nodeOne);
  }
```

Output:

```
{"company":"xyz","address":{"zipcode":"566258","state":"FL"}}
```

Disclaimer: While I do some JSON parsing and processing on a regular basis, I certainly wouldn't say that I'm adept at it or tree traversals with them. There is more than likely a better way to find the value of a child in a JsonNode than by taking the entire child as a node, replacing it's one value and then replacing the node. This should work for you in a pinch, though :)